# Loading vertices with a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, directx, vertices

I've created an algorithm that renders a heightmap in an array[x][y] which stores the z-value.
Now I want to load these into a vertices with a for loop. How would I do this?

I want to do this with directx btw.

Answer (score 0):

Fristly, create a vertex buffer(n*m)
Secondly, lock the buffer
Thirdly, copy values to the buffer by

```
for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
 for(int y=0;y<m;y++)
  vertex[x*m+y]=vector3(xvalue,yvalue,array[x][y]);
```

Finally, unlock the buffer.

Is this what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at any terrain rendering example like [Terrain Rendering Tutorial](http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/terrain/terrain01.html) or [Terrain Generation with a Heightmap](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/terrain-generation-with-a-heightmap/).